# Access an element while splitting a string

Tags: arrays, perl, variable-assignment

I want to retrieve a last element of the array. Array is a splitted string retrieved as follows:
`my @net_info = split(/\//,'10.0.0.2/8');`

I am interested only in the last element of the array, that is the CIDR value in one line. I was thinking of:
    `my $cidr = ${split(/\//,'10.0.0.2/8')}[-1];`

but that resulted in:
`Can't use string ("2") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at...`

Is it possible to get last element directly? What is the right syntax to achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for `split()` we see this:

> Splits the string EXPR into a list of strings and returns the list in list context, or the size of the list in scalar context

So we can get the list in an array:

```
my @net_info = split(/\//,'10.0.0.2/8');
```

And then get the last element of that array:

```
my $cidr = $net_info[-1];
```

But you can do it in one line of code by using a *list slice*. The syntax for a list slice is:

```
( LIST )[ INDEX ]
```

You were getting a little lost and using this:

```
${ LIST }[ INDEX ]
```

So the correct syntax for your problem is:

```
my $cidr = ( split(/\//,'10.0.0.2/8') )[-1];
```

In addition, your code might be a little easier to understand if you used a different delimiter for the regex that is the first argument to `split()` - thereby getting rid of the need to escape the slash.

```
my $cidr = ( split(m[/],'10.0.0.2/8') )[-1];
```

**Update:** Given that a netmask only ever contains a single slash, it might be easier to write something like:

```
my ($ip, $cidr) = split(m[/], '10.0.0.2/8');
```

Or (using `undef` to drop the first value returned by `split()`:

```
my (undef, $cidr) = split(m[/], '10.0.0.2/8');
```

**Update 2:** And to explain what was going in your original code. You were inadvertently using this construct:

```
${ ARRAYREF }[ INDEX ]
```

Which is the general version of one way to get the value of an element of an array when you only have a reference to the array (more commonly, of course, you'd use `ARRAYREF->[ INDEX ]`).

As the expression within `${ ... }` is expected to evaluate to an array reference and as array references are always scalar values, Perl evaluates the expression in scalar context. And as we see from the documentation extract above, in scalar context, `split()` returns the number of elements in the list - which will be 2. And "2" isn't an array reference, so you get the error that you've seen.

Comment: Clear now :)  All the examples noted! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The right syntax is:

```
my $cidr = (split(/\//,'10.0.0.2/8'))[-1];
```